# Quarto r set max height for text output or figures

Tags: r, r-markdown, quarto

I am trying to print a large text output within R and for my Quarto document I want to be able to scroll within that output if I want to read it all.

I cannot tell if this is a YAML setting I need, or a knitr code chunk setting that I need. I've seen some other options where people are creating CSS files...

[R markdown output size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36421231/r-markdown-output-size)

[How to make a horizontal scrollable in Quarto?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74280586/how-to-make-a-horizontal-scrollable-in-quarto)

I have to imagine there's a systematic way to control this behavior for both maximum vertical and horizontal scrolling?

Answer (score 1):

Well I figured out a way to control the height at least.

Created a css file with this inside and saved as "style.css"

```
.output {
  color: blue;
  max-height: 600px; /* can change this */
  max-width: 1200px; /* doesn't seem to have any effect */
  overflow: auto;
  background: #f0f0f5;
}
```

Then within my YAML in Quarto I added:

```
format: 
  html:
    css: style.css
```

Then within my chunk I used the class-output option like so:

````
```{r}
#| label: preview-data
#| include: true
#| code-line-numbers: true
#| class-output: output
print(1:5)
```
````

This does effectively add the css styling to the output of that block, and I can control vertical size before scroll, but horizontal is probably set in some other way?

Answer (score 0):

The width you could control using the [css grid system](https://quarto.org/docs/output-formats/page-layout.html#css-grid) or via css as well.

---

````
format: html
css: styles.css
---

## Grid System


::: {.grid}

::: {.g-col-7}

```{r}
#| class-output: scrolling
stringi::stri_rand_lipsum(50)
```

:::
:::

```{r}
#| class-output: scrolling
stringi::stri_rand_lipsum(50)
```
````

**styles.css**

```
.scrolling {
  max-height: 300px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  max-width: 600px;
}
```

[image]